# What statistical test to discriminate between within and between category with 2-dimensional data?

Tags: statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, inference, multiple-comparisons

Let's say I have a multidimensional data with one axis indicating factors of a customer base (eg. income), and another axis could show some options (eg. fashion store A, fashion store B, fashion store C). The matrix would contain values corresponding to the corresponding axis labels (a[i,j] shows the number of people from income class i who shop at store j). Yet another axis may indicate the grocery stores they might shop at. While the fashion stores might be correlated to the income classes, the grocery store choices might not.

My question is, how would I be able to analyse this matrix? Is there a particular test or algorithm that I should proceed with?

For one dimensional analysis - there is herfindahl test.

Comment: What kind of hypothesis you would like to test?

Comment: @Tim♦ I wish to understand if a specific income class is much more likely to go to a specific grocery store or not. And the same way for a fashion store. And also how likely are they to choose a specific fashion store rather than a specific grocery store. Let me know if my query is not clear!